# How can I change the icon/item size of a TListView in vsIcon ViewStyle?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, tlistview

I need a control which can display thumbnails, for this I thought `TListView` with the `ViewStyle` set as `vsIcon` would be good enough for my purposes, unfortunately I realised that `TImageList` only supports images up to 256x256 in size. I know there are 3rd party solutions for this but I had hoped to work with the standard `TListView`.

The images I need to display are approximately 348x480 so I cannot add them to a imagelist and assign it to a listview.

So then I thought maybe I could store my images in a `TList` and then ownerdraw the listview, it is quite simple really just by using the `CustomDrawItem` method and working with the `Item.DisplayRect` to know exactly where to draw to, something like this (quick example):

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1CustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView;
  Item: TListItem; State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
var
  ItemRect: TRect;
  IconRect: TRect;
  CaptionRect: TRect;
begin
  DefaultDraw := False;

  ItemRect := Item.DisplayRect(drBounds);
  IconRect := Item.DisplayRect(drIcon);
  CaptionRect := Item.DisplayRect(drLabel);

  with ListView1 do
  begin
    if cdsHot in State then
    begin
      Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
      Canvas.Brush.Color := clSkyBlue;
      Canvas.FillRect(ItemRect);
    end;

    if cdsSelected in State then
    begin
      Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
      Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlue;
      Canvas.FillRect(ItemRect);
    end;

    { my picture list is a custom control that holds bitmaps in a TList }
    if MyPictureList1.Items.Count > 0 then
      MyPictureList1.Draw(Canvas, IconRect.Left + 348 div 4, IconRect.Top + 2, Item.ImageIndex);

   // commented out old code drawing from imagelist
   { if LargeImages <> nil then
    begin
      LargeImages.Draw(Canvas, IconRect.Left + LargeImages.Width div 4, 2, Item.ImageIndex);
    end;  }

    // draw text etc
  end;
end;
```

The problem is how to change the size of each listview item? Typically setting the imagelist will change the size of the items, but I cannot use an imagelist because of the size limitations.

I had tried `ListView_SetIconSpacing(ListView1.Handle, 348, 480);` which did not seem to do anything, I also tried inflating the local rects I assigned but no luck there.

Is it possible to manually set the icon/item size of a listview to be greater than 256px and if so, how could I achieve this?

Comment: Do you really need to display such large images at one time? What about having the Listview display smaller thumbnails, and then let the user click on them to display the larger version in a separate window?

Comment: I realised I included `ListView_SetIconSpacing` in my question (I posted really late) this was a mistake, that was just something I was trying at one point. I know that only sets the spacing between items: [ListView_SetIconSpacing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775085%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes that is the obvious way to reduce the size of the images, for my purposes though I only needed to display about 8 thumbnails so the size was not a problem. Well it looks like I will just do that then, rather than hacking away at the listview.

Comment: This is an image list control limitation, you cannot do anything with it. Why don't you want to use `TDrawGrid` instead?

Comment: Which version of Delphi? By the sound of it, you may be better off using something like a `TFlowPanel` or `TGridPanel` with speed buttons on it, if you only have to show 8 icons. But those controls are only in later versions of Delphi.

Comment: @JerryDodge I am using Delphi XE7, but I decided to rethink my design now instead. I guess I was more curious if it was at all possible to set the icon/item size manually in a listview control without attaching a imagelist but this is no longer a priority.

Comment: @Craig: What did you end up doing? I am in the same situation. I want to do a simple app that displays images from a directory. A while ago I've done an app in QT and I used their QListView component which was perfect. Trying to do the same in Delphi I hit the same issues you describe. Another approach would be to use an embedded browser (let's say, chromium, see: https://github.com/hgourvest/dcef3) and generate html that would display the images from the local hard-drive via file://... uris.